# change css of box when window resize doesn't work very well

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i try to do an script that when i click on resized image of gallery; the image is showed in box in the middle of screen. But if the window is resized and the width of "orginal" image is bigger than width of box; box's css must change.

So if box's width is < image's width

```
$('#box').css('left', '0%');
$('#box').css('transform','translate3d(0%,0,0)');
```

Else

```
$('#box').css('left', '50%');
$('#box').css('transform','translate3d(-50%,0,0)');
```

This is js:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $('#boximmagini img').click(function(){
        $("#immagine img:last-child").remove()
        var source= $(this).attr('src'); 
        var i2= new Image();
        i2.onload = function() {
            var largimage= i2.width;         
        };
        i2.src = source;

        $('#immagine').append("<img src="+source+" style='width: 100%;border-radius:10px; margin-top:30px'/>")
        $('#overlay').fadeIn('fast');
        $('#box').fadeIn('slow');
        var largbox=$('#box').width();

        if(largbox< i2.width){
            $('#box').css('left', '0%');
            $('#box').css('transform','translate3d(0%,0,0)');
        } 
        else {
            $('#box').css('left', '50%');
            $('#box').css('transform','translate3d(-50%,0,0)');
        }        
        $(window).resize(function() {
            var resizelargbox= $('#box').width(); 
            if (largbox != resizelargbox) {
                largbox = resizelargbox;
                var Laggiungi= '<span style="color: #fff">'+largbox+'</span><br>';
                $(Laggiungi).appendTo('#larghezza');
                if(largbox< i2.width){
                    $('#box').css('left', '0%');
                    $('#box').css('transform','translate3d(0%,0,0)');
                } 
                else {
                    $('#box').css('left', '50%');
                    $('#box').css('transform','translate3d(-50%,0,0)');
                }
            }
        }); 
    });

    $(".chiudi").click(function(){
        $('#overlay').fadeOut('fast');
        $('#box').hide();
    });

    //chiusura emergenza
    $("#overlay").click(function(){
        $(this).fadeOut('fast');
        $('#box').hide();
    });
});
```

**This is Jsfiddle** 
http://jsfiddle.net/tvafw5Ls/

The problem is when **box's width is > image's width**, He starts to go in spurts, as if the code does not know the actual width of the box. Through the added values in the span width ** ** you can see the width of the box every time the window is resized. If you click on the first image to the left; as soon as the window exceeds the width of the image (that its natural width is 488 px), he starts giving problems.

I hope that you can help me.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not able to properly understand what you need, I think you need this - http://jsfiddle.net/tvafw5Ls/1/

Comment: @RohitKumar doesn't work..  to understand see this updatehttp://jsfiddle.net/tvafw5Ls/2/  when box's width is bigger than image's width, i must add at box "left: 50%" and transform property. But doesn't work... do you understand now ? (the box must be in the middle of screen)

Comment: okay got that, do you I've a fixed `width` or `max-width` of the `#box` set? I can't see in the fiddle you have provide, you have to set a `width` to get it properly working.

Comment: See now http://jsfiddle.net/tvafw5Ls/2/   (i don't have a fixed width, because i don't know the width of other images and also because the box must changes width when window is resized). If you look this update is better...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/tvafw5Ls/7/

I have changed my past code and i worked on width of image

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#boximmagini img').click(function () {
    $("#immagine img:last-child").remove()
    var source = $(this).attr('src');
    var i2 = new Image();
    i2.onload = function () {
        var largimage = i2.width;
    };
    i2.src = source;

    $('#immagine').append("<img src=" + source + " style='width:100%; border-radius:10px; margin-top:30px'/>")
    $('#overlay').fadeIn('fast');
    $('#box').fadeIn('slow');
    //
    $('#box').css('left', '0%');
    $("#immagine img:last-child").css('width', '100%');
    //
    var widthimage = $("#immagine img:last-child").width();

    if (widthimage < i2.width) {
        $('#box').css('left', '0%');
        $('#box').css('transform', 'translate3d(0%,0,0)');
        $("#immagine img:last-child").css('width', '100%');
    } else {
        $('#box').css('left', '50%');
        $("#immagine img:last-child").css('width', '');
        $('#box').css('transform', 'translate3d(-50%,0,0)');
    }



    $(window).resize(function () {
         $('#box').css('left', '0%');
        $("#immagine img:last-child").css('width', '100%');
        var widthimage = $("#immagine img:last-child").width();           
        if (widthimage < i2.width) {
            $('#box').css('left', '0%');
            $("#immagine img:last-child").css('width', '100%');
            $('#box').css('transform', 'translate3d(0%,0,0)');

        } else {
            $('#box').css('left', '50%');
            $("#immagine img:last-child").css('width', '');
            $('#box').css('transform', 'translate3d(-50%,0,0)');

        }

    });
});

$(".chiudi").click(function () {
    $('#overlay').fadeOut('fast');
    $('#box').hide();
});

//chiusura emergenza
$("#overlay").click(function () {
    $(this).fadeOut('fast');
    $('#box').hide();
});
```

});

Comment: Let's close this question now

Comment: Tick the check mark against your answer. For more info check this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work